# Aggregate weekly data into Month data giving weight to first and last week

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database containing several years of the price values of a product, based on the number of the week (ISO8601 definition).

Now I need to aggregate this data by month, but considering also the weight of the week in that each month. For example, if the week has only 3 days in the current month, I need to give this week a weight of 3/7, therefore the price value will be (3/7)*price.

I've started to write this code but I'm completely stuck on how to proceed.
Is there a simple way to do it, or I need to loop through all the years-month, one by one, and calculate the weight this way? (maybe directly with LINQ or SQL)

Additionally, I'm not able to get the number of the weeks (ISO-8601 definition, 1 to 53) that are contained in the months I'm looping

For example in January 2021 we have the weeks:

- 53 of 2020 (partial, only 3 days)
- 01 of 2021
- 02 of 2021
- 03 of 2021
  etc..

```
public static decimal GetWeightedMonthlyPrice(int year, int week, int month, decimal priceValue)
{
    DateTime startDate = FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(year,week);
    
    //get weight of the week in the month
    int daysInTheMonth=0;
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        if(startDate.AddDays(i).Month==month){
            daysInTheMonth++;
        }
    }
    decimal weightedPrice= (daysInTheMonth/7m)*priceValue; //the weighted price for the current month
    return weightedPrice;
}
```

and

```
public static DateTime FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(int year, int weekOfYear)
{
    DateTime jan1 = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    int daysOffset = DayOfWeek.Thursday - jan1.DayOfWeek;
    DateTime firstThursday = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset);
    var cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
    int firstWeek = cal.GetWeekOfYear(firstThursday, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
    var weekNum = weekOfYear;
    if (firstWeek == 1)
    {
        weekNum -= 1;
    }
    var result = firstThursday.AddDays(weekNum * 7);
    return result.AddDays(-3);
}
```

Comment: I already see an error: `(daysInTheMonth/7)` is an integer division. You want `(daysInTheMonth/7m)`, otherwise 8/7 = 1, or you can directly `daysInTheMonth * priceValue  / 7` (first multiply then divide), `priceValue` is `decimal` so there is a guaranteed promotion in the multiplication.

Comment: @xanatos thanks corrected. (the code is written here on the fly, not yet in VS. I need to find the correct algorithm)

Comment: I see another problem... A week that spans the end of January and the beginning of february... You would count a piece on Jan and a piece on Feb... But your method has the month in input but no way to communicate to the caller that the same week must be "reused" for the next month. Probably putting the `month` as a `ref` so that the method can change it.

Comment: @xantos, yes is exactly what I'm asking in my question, get the partial days of weeks that fall in a month in order to calculate the weight of the weeks. They can be at the beginning but also at the end. How can I get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in C#, probably something like:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="year"></param>
/// <param name="week"></param>
/// <param name="priceValue"></param>
/// <param name="month1">0 == december of year - 1</param>
/// <param name="weightedPrice1"></param>
/// <param name="month2">13 == january of year + 1, null == the week is fully contained in month1</param>
/// <param name="weightedPrice2">null == the week is fully contained in month1</param>
public static void GetWeightedMonthlyPrice(int year, int week, decimal priceValue, out int month1, out decimal weightedPrice1, out int? month2, out decimal? weightedPrice2)
{
    DateTime startDate = FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(year, week);

    month1 = startDate.Month;

    int days1 = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month1) - startDate.Day + 1;
    weightedPrice1 = days1 * priceValue / 7m;

    int days2 = 7 - days1;

    if (days2 != 0)
    {
        month2 = month1 + 1;
        weightedPrice2 = days2 * priceValue / 7m;
    }
    else
    {
        month2 = null;
        weightedPrice2 = null;
    }

    if (month1 == 12)
    {
        month1 = 0;
    }
}
```

Note that the `month` isn't an input parameter, but is an **output** parameter, and there can be two `month`s as output parameter (if the weighted price must be splitted).

Faster solutions can be probably built in C# if you can cache the `firstThursday` of `FirstDateOfWeekISO8601` between calls (not that it is "slow", but I hate to know that it is being recalculated 52 or 53 times a year). Solutions can even be built SQL side.